# Theano logistic SGD with per-dimension learning rates

Tags: numpy, theano

Here's a very simple, beginner Theano question.

I'm trying to modify the Logistic SGD code provided with the [Deep Learning Tutorials](http://www.deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html#logreg), to switch from a single learning rate to a learning rate that would be dimension-specific. For instance if I have 3 input dimensions, I would like to use 3 different learning rates, one per dimension.

The original relevant code is:

```
learning_rate = 0.1
x = T.matrix('x')
y = T.ivector('y')
classifier = LogisticRegression(input=x, n_in=3, n_out=2)
cost = classifier.negative_log_likelihood(y)

g_W = T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=classifier.W)
g_b = T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=classifier.b)

updates = [(classifier.W, classifier.W - learning_rate * g_W),
           (classifier.b, classifier.b - learning_rate * g_b)]

train_model = theano.function(inputs=[],
        outputs=cost,
        updates=updates,
        givens={
            x: minibatch_x,
            y: minibatch_y})
```

In numpy, it would be simply a matter of replacing the scalar learning rate with an array of learning rates and perform element-wise multiplication with the gradients g_W and g_b. In Theano doing so yields an error:

```
'Expected an array-like object, but found a Variable: maybe you are trying to call a function on a (possibly shared) variable instead of a numeric array?'
```

Clearly there is something about Theano that I'm missing. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you need to replace the learning rate scalar by an array. You can try e.g. the following:

```
learning_rate = theano.shared(np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.05]))
```

It may need to be transposed depending on the shape of the gradient, but essentially you have stated the correct way to go and it should work using a shared variable.